# Upload file which stored in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-storage, webclient, azure-blob-storage

I have to upload a file to Listen360 through webclient but my file is stored in Azure blob storage. When I give URL of saved file in blob storage as the path, it gives "URI formats are not supported."

UploadFile(URI, filename)

It work when I give a local path to filename but not for blob storage url of stored file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what `UploadFile()` is. But... blobs are not the same as local files - you cannot use standard I/O libraries with blobs. Can you please edit your question to be more specific where you're passing the URL to `UploadFile()`? (meaning... are you passing a blob url as the `filename` parameter?)

Comment: Edited the question and I need to pass blob url as a filename.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to download the file locally, and dump it in to temp folder, then delete it, assuming that's the only way you can do it.

```
string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml";

using(var client = new WebClient ())
{
   client.DownloadFile(blob.URL, fileName);

   UploadFile(fileName, "mystuff.xml");
   File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Comment: My system is hosted in azure cloud. will it be possible to save that downloaded file in a local path?

Answer (score 0):

[WebClient.UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144229(v=vs.110).aspx) just allows to upload the specified local file to a resource with the specified URI. We can use stream to upload the file to a resource. The following is my sample demo code. It works correctly for me.

```
       using (var client = new WebClient())
       {
           var download = client.DownloadData("blob url");
           client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"userName","password");// Some code for authenticating
           var clientStream =client.OpenWrite(new Uri("your Url"));
           clientStream.Write(download, 0, download.Length);
           clientStream.Close();
       }
```